# How to Clone HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, clone

I want to set some properties of an `HttpWebRequest` and then download some files asynchronously. However, I need one copy of `HttpWebRequest` for each download, so how can I clone it so that I don't have to copy each property "by hand"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpWebRequest does not support serialization or cloning, thus you have to implement your own mechanism to save/copy it. You can use serialized (or clonable) derived class or some wrapper for this task.

Comment: That's unfortunate... I think everything should have a `Clone()` method, but oh well.

Comment: How would you clone the open network connection that's part of the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: @John Saunders
Connection property in HttpWebRequest is just a header, not a physical connection. And processing HttpWebResponse is another task here.

Comment: @John: Oh, well I don't really care about the connection anyway. I just want the properties. Actually, I basically want to use it as a 'template'; I want to copy it before any connection is made.

Answer (score 2):

Create your own class to hold the properties you're interested in. That class can implement `IClonable` if necessary. In any case, use these properties to initialize each new instance of `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: So... you're saying I have to list them all out? That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: There's no such thing as magic. A class that is not clonable cannot be cloned. If it can't be serialized, then you can't serialize it. That's life.

Comment: No one said anything about magic. I was hoping maybe I could do some kind of introspection and nab the properties that way... who knows. I'm discovering all sorts of things about C# still...

Comment: "Reflection", not "introspection". You could use Reflection to capture all the public read/write properties of one instance, and to copy them to another instance.

Answer (score 2):

you need to be careful when creating a number of connection using HttpWebRequest.
http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2006/09/net-20-httpwebrequestkeepalive-and.html
 As it is not serializable you can create a wrapper class

Comment: Hrm... well, I went through great pains to put a cap on the number of connections anyway. I only intend on using about 8.